# Kaplan Meier Estimator with a second dimension

Tags: statistics, qliksense

I succeed to implement the Kaplan Meier estimator inside a line chart in Qlik Sense
like this

[image: Kaplan Meier]

To do that, I write this expression which is the exact transcription of KM Estimator

```
= if(RowNo() = 1, 1, 
    (1 - (count({<Analyse_Type = {'Churn'}>}%Key_Contract) /
          count({<Analyse_Type = {'Parc'}>}%Key_Contract)))  * above(Column(1))
)
```

Everything works fine but I'd like to add a second dimension in the graph and when I do that, the recursive *above* seems to get muddle up.

I try to aggregate the *above* by my second dimension but it is not working.

Does someone have an idea to do that? Or another way to write the Kaplan Meier estimator without the  using of a recursion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution to my issue.

I switch the way to make a accumulation of product (the recursive above) by the mathematical logic 
exp(rangeSum(log())). I aggregate the rangeSum by my second dimension ordered by my first dimension (the interval) and everything works fine.

Here the final expression of the Kaplan Meier Estimator:

```
exp(aggr(Rangesum(Above(log(fabs(  
    (1 - (count({<Analyse_Type = {'Churn'}>}%Key_Contract) / count({<Analyse_Type 
    {'SurvivalParc'}>}%Key_Contract)))) ),0, Rowno()))  
, REGION, (Delivered_Days_5, NUMERIC, ASCENDING)))
```

And here is the visual result:

[image]